# Start.process does not work with VSIXInstaller.exe arguments C#

Tags: c#, vsix

I am trying to run the process to uninstall a certain VS Extension with on a quite mode and it seems the arguments won't pass.

```
string VSIXInstallerPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config", "VSIXInstallerLocation", null);
          Process UninstallVSPackage = new Process();
          UninstallVSPackage = Process.Start(VSIXInstallerPath + " " + (@"/u:GUID /quiet"));
```

And this is the error I get:

> The system cannot find the file specified

When I run from Command Prompts it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a command with arguments, you have to use the [`Process.Start(string fileName, string argument)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) overload and pass the arguments to the second parameters.

```
UninstallVSPackage = Process.Start(VSIXInstallerPath, "/u:GUID /quiet");
```

Comment: I've used your example, the string turns out to : "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\\\Common7\\IDE\\VSIXInstaller.exe\"  /u:GUID /quiet" but still same error.